# r: function arguments matched to variables rather then ellipsis

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

here is my function:

```
print.log <- function(print.flag = T,...){
  if(print.flag)
    print(paste(as.character(Sys.time()),' - ',...))
}
```

function call:

```
print.log('listing x files')
```

error message:
    Error in if (print.flag) print(paste(as.character(Sys.time()), " - ",  : 
      argument is not interpretable as logical

here is the value print.flag holds:

```
Browse[2]> print.flag
[1] "listing x files"
```

I understand that the string I wanted to push to the ellipsis was matched after all to the print.flag variable.

my question: why is that the behavior,  and how can I fixed it to achieve the desired result?
(meaning, all function arguments will go to the ellipsis, unless I specifically declare the print.flag variable  )

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is actually pretty easy: switch the order of your arguments.

```
print.log <- function(..., print.flag = T){
  if(print.flag)
    print(paste(as.character(Sys.time()),' - ',...))
}
```

The reason this works is that unnamed parameters in a function call are matched in the order they are named in the function definition.  This happens until you hit `...`, which greedily eats up all unnamed (or named and not mentioned, for that matter) arguments.

```
print.log("a", "b", "c")
#> [1] "2017-07-30 05:21:08  -  a b c"

print.log("a", print.flag = F)

print.log("a", print.flag = T, "b")
#> [1] "2017-07-30 05:21:08  -  a b"

print.log("a", one = "b", two = "c")
#> [1] "2017-07-30 05:21:08  -  a b c"
```

NOTE: perhaps to answer a few questions you did not ask.

Be careful using `.` as a naming convention (despite many base `R` functions that do not follow this advice), as the `.` is used by `S3` for class behavior.  More reading [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html).

Also, you might look into the [`logging`](http://logging.r-forge.r-project.org/) package, which is an R port of the popular python logging package.  It allows environmental control of logging with "logging level" and defining a default formatting (in your case, timestamp in front, etc.).

Comment: @kamashay If my answer solves your problem, please accept the answer to show that your question has been answered sufficiently.

Comment: great answer and great comments. this indeed solves the issue.